# Get keyname from datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using named key for an ndb entity:

```
entity = MyEntity(id='MyNamedKey', count=mycount)
```

When I get the entity from the datastore the key for the entity is of type "Key" and looks like this:

```
Key('MyEntity', 'MyNamedKey')
```

What would be a good way to get the "MyNamedKey" part from the key?

I tried the following but its probably not the right way to do it

```
entity.key._Key__pairs[0][1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a cursory reading of [NDB Key Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass), looks like the `id()` or `string_id()` methods would be appropriate.